# Magento 2 two different magento having same cart value

Tags: magento2, cart, session, cookie

I have installed two magento on my local server.*I added product from my first magento installation its added fine but it also display in second magento installation*. **Why does this happen? Any one have same issue?**

[image]

[image]

Display product in cart in second image it is not exists in my second magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your URLs, **my guess is that your two Magento installations share the cookies and/or sessions.**

As they use the same base URLs, the cookies from the second install are being shared with the second installation.

I suggest you **avoid using the same URLs for two different installations and setup proper different hosts for each installation.**

Answer (score 1):

You are using same URL for 2 sites. So the cookies will be shared.
You should create different Url for each site.
Example:
Site 1: magento2.mcs.com
Site2 : magento202.mcs.com

You can reference this document for create virtual host:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html